# Linking to a static library that requires a frameworks

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, static-libraries, build-script

I have a main project and a few smaller sub-projects. The smaller projects contain both a self contained Cocos2d app and a static library containing only the classes that are relevant to the main project (the sub-projects all use the Cocos2D framework). The main project is dependant on the static libraries. I think this approach is theoretically sound, but in practice it is not working.

The symptom I am seeing is as follows: When the code is executed as part of the main project the pre-processor values work. When I run the app of a subproject it runs as expected.

I have set the `-all_load` linker option in the main target. This is because the classes in the sub-projects are only mentioned in nib files. Without `-all_load` the classes are 'optimized' out of the main target as the compiler incorrectly determines the code to be superfluous.

I have linked all of the sub-projects to the .frameworks that they require.

Is this fixable or is this approach doomed to fail? How else can I manage these projects without static libraries? Other developers work on the sub-projects and the static library approach prevents us from getting in each others way.

### Update

Reading that question back makes me think I should have taken a break a lot earlier! The question doesn't explain the problem very well (or make much sense!). The problem relates to how to use sub-projects to organise code. I've now almost solved the issue. I'll probably write a blog post when I've fully solved it.

Comment: Sorry, but it is not clear to me what is not working for you...

Answer (score 0):

Since the static libraries end up "baked in" to your executable, you don't need to concern yourself with their linking anymore than you need your executable.

Just set up the project dependencies so that the dependent framework builds first (so the .framework/Headers folder gets populated properly), then the libraries, then your app. I have done this in multiple apps with great success.